# Why does this Vim RegEx search and replace not match?

Tags: regex, vim

I'm attempting to use the following Vim RegEx pattern:

```
%s/\(<Column>[\ \t\nA-Za-z0-9\<\>\/]\+<Name>[ \t\n]*Code[ \t\n]*<\/Name>\([\ \t\nA-Za-z0-9\<\>\/]\)\{-}<\/Column>\)//g
```

I have also attempted:

```
%s/\v(\<Column\>[\s\w\<\>\/]+\<Name\>\s*Code\s*\<\/Name\>([\s\w\<\>\/]){-}\<\/Column\>)//g
```

The string I'm matching against has the form (of many lines) of this:

```
<Table>
  <Name>NameOfThing</Name>
  <Description>Description of thing</Description>
  <Type>Data</Type>
  <Columns>
    <Column>
      <Name>Code</Name>
      <Description>Things Code</Description>
      <Type>String</Type>
      <Length>254</Length>
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Name>TypeCode</Name>
      <Description>Things type code</Description>
      <Type>String</Type>
      <Length>254</Length>
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Name>Name</Name>
      <Description>Things Name</Description>
      <Type>String</Type>
      <Length>254</Length>
    </Column>
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

I am trying to capture and remove only the portion that looks like this:

```
    <Column>
      <Name>Code</Name>
      <Description>Things Code</Description>
      <Type>String</Type>
      <Length>254</Length>
    </Column>
```

When I convert the regular expression pattern syntax into something that PCRE accepts, it captures what I need correctly:

```
(<Column>[\s\w\<\>\/]+<Name>[ \t\n]*Code[ \t\n]*<\/Name>[\s\w\<\>\/]+?<\/Column>)
```

What am I missing here?

---

Edit: I am silly, my first attempt is working, but I had not fixed it in Vim after fixing it elsewhere.

However - I'm still curious as to why the other form with the magic `\v` does not work:

```
%s/\v(\<Column\>[ \t\nA-Za-z0-9\<\>\/]+\<Name\>[ \t\n]*Code[ \t\n]*\<\/Name\>[ \t\n\<\>\/]{-}\<\/Column\>)//g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s` is character class it-self. You can't use `\s` or `\w` in `[]`. If you want to use it, you must use `[[:space:]]` instead. `[\s]` only match `\` and `s`.

And you can use `\_` modifier for `.{-}`. This can include the end-of-line.

```
%s/\v(\<Column\>\_.{-}\<Name\>\s*Code\s*\<\/Name\>\_.{-}\<\/Column\>)//g
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a substitution.

```
:g/>Code</-1,+4d
```

See:

```
:help :g
:help :range
:help :d
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I don't believe this is an answer. I could use that as a comment.  My question is specifically: "Why does this regex not work?"  Thank you, though!